# Как сделать так, что бы тг бот реагировал на слова?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Мне нужно что бы после того как пользователь нажал на инлайн кнопку и отправилось сообщение "оплата", бот реагировал на это слово и присылал сообщение, как это сделать?

```
import asyncio 
 
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F 
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandStart 
from aiogram.types import Message, LabeledPrice, PreCheckoutQuery 
 
import os 
import logging 
 
import keyboards 
 
#token 
bot = Bot('') 
dp = Dispatcher() 
 
 
 
@dp.message(Command("start")) 
async def start(message: Message): 
    await message.answer('Привет.', reply_markup=keyboards.main_kb) 
 
 
@dp.message() 
async def echo(message: Message): 
    msg = message.text.lower() 
 
    if msg == 'помощь': 
        await message.answer('Моя контактная информация:', reply_markup=keyboards.links_kb) 
    elif msg == 'купить': 
        await message.answer("покупка", 
                             reply_markup=keyboards.pof_kb) 
 
 
@dp.message(F.text.lower().in_(['оплатить'])) 
async def order(message: Message, bot: Bot): 
    await bot.send_invoice( 
            chat_id=message.chat.id, 
            title="Покупка курса", 
            description='Оплата курса', 
            payload='Payment', 
            provider_token='', 
            currency='rub', 
            prices=[LabeledPrice(label='Покупка курса', amount=39900)], 
            start_parameter='fount-of-discounts', 
            is_flexible=False, 
            disable_notification=True, 
            allow_sending_without_reply=True, 
            request_timeout=30 
    ) 
async def pre_checkout_query(precheckoutquery: PreCheckoutQuery, bot: Bot): 
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_query.id, ok=True) 
 
 
 
async def main(): 
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True) 
    await dp.start_polling(bot) 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    asyncio.run(main())
```

```
from aiogram.types import ( 
    ReplyKeyboardMarkup, 
    KeyboardButton, 
    InlineKeyboardMarkup, 
    InlineKeyboardButton 
) 
 
main_kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup( 
    keyboard=[ 
        [ 
            KeyboardButton(text='Хочу купить сборник'), 
            KeyboardButton(text='Помощь') 
        ] 
    ], 
    resize_keyboard=True, 
    one_time_keyboard=True, 
    input_field_placeholder='Выберите действие из меню' 
) 
 
links_kb = InlineKeyboardMarkup( 
    inline_keyboard=[ 
        [ 
            InlineKeyboardButton(text="VK", url="-"), 
            InlineKeyboardButton(text="Telegram", url="-"), 
            InlineKeyboardButton(text="Instagram", url="-") 
        ] 
    ] 
) 
 
 
pof_kb = ReplyKeyboardMarkup( 
    keyboard=[ 
        [ 
            KeyboardButton(text='Оплатить') 
        ] 
    ], 
    resize_keyboard=True, 
    one_time_keyboard=True, 
    input_field_placeholder='Выберите действие из меню' 
)
```

Comment: т.к. вы не предоставили свой код, то пусть будет так `if message.text == 'оплата'`

Comment: Я добавил код, после кнопки оплаты бот молчит